# nunit large project integration tests, out of memory exception

Tags: memory, nunit, out-of-memory, red-gate-ants

I'm using nunit for running integration tests (which each test interacts with the database via nhibernate) for a large project with 600+ tests. problem is after 10-15 minutes minutes nunit throws out of memory exception. I used redgate ants memory profiler to see why nunit is not releasing memory between the tests. seems it tries to recreate permission objects per test and memory keeps growing and eventually it throws out of memory exception.

I took snapshots on one integration test class but you can see the memory keeps growing after awhile. I didn't find any call or setting for nunit to force memory release or solve this trust issue.

I really appreciate any help.

```
<NamedPermissionSets><PermissionSet class=\\"System.Security.NamedPermissionSet\\"version=\\"1\\" Unrestricted=\\"true\\" Name=\\"Full ...
```

ANTS Snapshots:

http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/IXwb8Q.jpg

http://www.tinyuploads.com/images/3R2VbB.png

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell which version you're using, but your problem might have been fixed in NUnit 2.6.3. See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+bug/1069666) for the bug report.

Comment: thanks for the info, but test implementation was wrong. castle container was getting initialized many times..